# bin sh start multiple processes

Tags: shell, service, terminal, bin

I am trying to start multiple processes for my development server by creating a #!/bin/sh file with shell commands in it.

E.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Start all servers? (Y/n)" answer
if test "$answer" = "Y"
then
    cd ./www/src; node ./index.js;
    cd ./www/; ./gulp;
    cd ./api/; nodemon ./init.js;
    cd ./api-test/; node ./index.js;
else
    echo "Cancelled."   
fi
```

Because for example nodemon will setup a watch process or node a http server process, the first command will start (cd ./www/src; node ./index.js;) and not continue to startup the other processes.

I can't figure out how to start all 4 processes independent of each other..

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to write some functions to spawn each process consistently:

- One function called `spawn_once` will only run the command if it is not already running, therefore allowing only one instance
- One second function  called `spawn` will run the command even if it is already running (allow multiple instances)

Use the most appropriate for your use case

```
#!/bin/sh

# Spawn command $1 from path $2
spawn() {
    local cmd=$1; local path=$2
    ( [ ! -z "$path" ] && cd "$path"; eval "$cmd"; ) &
}


# Spawn command $1 from path $2, only if command $1 is not running
# in other words, run only a single instance
spawn_once() {
    local cmd=$1; local path=$2
    ( 
      [ ! -z "$path" ] && cd "$path"
      pgrep -u "$USER" -x "$cmd" >/dev/null || eval "$cmd"
    ) &
}


# Use spawn or spawn_once to start your multiple commands
# The format is: spawn "<command with args>" "<path>"
spawn "node ./index.js" "./www/src"
spawn_once "./gulp" "./www/"  # only one instance allowed
spawn "node ./index.js" "./api-test/"
```

Explanation:

- `( [ ! -z "$path" ] && cd "$path"; eval "$cmd"; ) &` : Change directory (if path argument was set) and run the command in a subshell (`&`), i.e. in the background, so it does not affect the current directory for other commands and does not block the script while the command is running.
- spawn_once: `pgrep -u "$USER" -x "$cmd" >/dev/null || eval "$cmd"` : Check if the command has already been started with `pgrep`, otherwise (`||`) run the command.

Comment: In this case I get the following error: "./startup: 3: ./startup: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"..

Comment: Are you enclosing the command with its arguments in quotes as shown above? Can you show me your exact script? You can use pastebin/gist etc.

Comment: Your script is working properly for me without errors. What is the output of `/bin/sh --version` in your system? What OS are you using? I also made some edits to improve compatibility for older shells. You may try again with the new version. Finally, you may try changing the first line (shebang) to `#! /usr/bin/bash`  (if bash is available) to check whether your `/bin/sh` is an old-shell not supporting functions

Comment: Thank you @henfiber! Changing #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash seem to have solved the problem :) And thanks for the excellent functions above, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it works for you. If you think this answer addresses your question, you may mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ampersand "&" to execute task in background

for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Start all servers? (Y/n)" answer
if test "$answer" = "Y"
then
    cd ./www/src
    node ./index.js &
    cd $OLDPWD && cd ./www/
    ./gulp &
.........

else
    echo "Cancelled."   
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. But the pushd command produces errors: ./startup: 6: ./startup: pushd: not found
./startup: 8: ./startup: popd: not found
./startup: 9: ./startup: pushd: not found./startup: 6: ./startup: pushd: not found

Comment: So use cd instead, that's correct too.. Don't forget change to correct directory for each command